# Displaying View Controller on top of other when app starts does not work in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I use following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    ...
    window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (self.requireLogin){
        [self.viewController presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

So i push loginViewController on top of viewController. This works ok on iOS prior to 8, but on iOS 8 you can see for small amount of time the viewController.

Is there simple way to present view controller on iOS 8 without showing what is behind it ?

Edit:
Noticed in log that it has also "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" so think ios 8 runs some animation on self.viewController. Is there way to stop it animating ?

Comment: presenting self.viewController on self.viewController without allocating self.requireLogin????

Comment: typo in code, fixing it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **Hide Initially, then unhide it.**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    // Hide initially
    window.rootViewController.view.hidden = YES;

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (self.requireLogin){
        [self.viewController presentViewController:yourloginViewController animated:NO completion:^{

            // Unhide now
            window.rootViewController.view.hidden = NO;

        }];
    }
}
```

Based on the response , It seems to be not showing the splash screen, So my better suggestion is

1. As you knew the YES/No to show the login view(based on self.requireLogin), you make login view controller as rootviewcontroller of your window.

   ```
   if (self.requireLogin){

       window.rootViewController = yourLoginViewController;

   }
   else{

       window.rootViewController = normalViewController;

   }
   ```
2. Still you need to use the same strategy of yours then add one UIImageView on the normal View Controller, then present login view controller.

The option is yours:)

Comment: Why you need hiding view of rootViewController ??? It also work without hiding it, isn't it??

Comment: Tried that already, it shows the black background instead of app startup screen.

Comment: Thanks for update, yeah think it would work, but not an easy change as later i need to update the code which hides the login view. Would prefer not to modify the hierarchy of controllers.

Comment: Used strategy 2, added custom view and removed it after animation finished. But would be nice if there would be way to stop the ios8 animation on start, as it's the cause of the issue.